# Adding Thunderbolt 3 capability to desktop

Tags: pci-express, usb-c, thunderbolt

I have a desktop for which I desired to utilize the front panel usb c port as a thunderbolt aware connection.  I subsequently realized since I do not have a lighting icon next to the port it is not thunderbolt capable.  Is there any way to add thunderbolt capabilities to a desktop?

I have the Lenovo IdeaCenter Creator Edition 5i desktop.  I have one space for a pci card for which a Graphics card is attached.  I was hoping to attach an external pci e card enclosure via Thunderbolt.

Is there a docking station or some interface like esata/usb3 to thunderbolt to be able to address the dilemma  Unfortunately, the presence of only one place for card expansion leaves little room to add other cards.

What options are available?

Comment: The short and the long answers are both no.

Comment: Seems the only way I envisioned was a motherboard upgrade, which is not practical, in my case, thank you.